# Return text next to search term based on phrase in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I'm trying to put together where I have a search phrases in the database that we use to query our fulltext index. Currently the below query is working.

```
select top 100  p.ID, dtp.Phrase,      
from table1 p 
left join table2 d on d.PropertyId = p.PropertyId 
left join table3 dt on dt.DocumentId = d.DocumentId 
left join table4 dtm on dtm.DocumentTextId = dt.DocumentTextId 
left join table 5 dtp on dtm.DocumentTypePhraseId = dtp.DocumentTypePhraseId
```

However I also want to include a portion of the searched text after dtp.Phrase. I was considering doing a subquery in the select statement.

```
select top 100  p.ID, dtp.Phrase, 
(
select sdt.DocText 
from mytable sdt 
where sdt.Doctextid = dt.doctextid    ) as DocText 
from table1 p 
left join table2 d on d.PropertyId = p.PropertyId 
left join table3 dt on dt.DocumentId = d.DocumentId 
left join table4 dtm on dtm.DocumentTextId = dt.DocumentTextId 
left join table5 dtp on dtm.DocumentTypePhraseId = dtp.DocumentTypePhraseId 
where   p.ID in ('1053468')
```

The DocText I want returned. Here's an example.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec ullamcorper tellus. Integer ac dui enim. Morbi lorem lorem, convallis a dolor ac, facilisis malesuada est. Sed mauris massa, consequat et pulvinar vitae, hendrerit sed ligula. Nam ornare blandit nisi sed euismod. Nunc dictum neque vitae mi sagittis, quis convallis ante maximus. Nullam a erat vitae dolor porttitor feugiat vel vel nisl. Quisque turpis sapien, ullamcorper a malesuada in, pellentesque faucibus nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean diam est, tincidunt in ultrices vel, venenatis ut dolor.

In the paragraph above let's say I want to search for the word maximus. But I don't want to return the entire paragraph. I just want to return the following

> quis convallis ante maximus. Nullam a erat vitae

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your FROM on the main query?

Comment: It's a table with items that I'm passing the customer id so I can grab the row id. then I drill down the other tables to get the info I may need to display.

Comment: How is sdt.DocText separated?  Are there linefeeds in it?

Comment: You talk about words and phrases and yet I see no reference in the data model.  What you are trying to do is unclear.

Comment: @Patrick It's OCR text from pdf documents. I'm assuming there could be line feeds. Or not depending on what the ocr software decided to do.

Comment: It will need to have some separator in order for you to parse it like you want to.  If it's just one long string with no breaks, you can not do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the phrases are the ones we use to match certain things in the ocr text. for example a search phrase could be " "this" Near "that*" and not ("not this 1" or "not this 2" or "not this 3") "